# Вывод содержимого vector

Tags: c++, vector

в dll описан класс Position, в main не получается вывести содержимое, когда очередь доходит до вывода, то выскакивает ошибка просто выскакивает окно с ошибкой. Пробовал еще вывести через for_each, но такая же ошибка

```
//POSITION.H
#pragma once
#ifdef POSITIONDLL_EXPORTS
#define POSITIONDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define POSITIONDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"

class POSITIONDLL_API Position
    {
    private:
        string positionName;
        string duties;
        int hoursOfWork;
        double salary;
    public:
        Position();
        ~Position();
        void addPosition(Position* CurPosition, vector<Position*> &AllPositions);

        void setPosName(string CurPosName);
        void setDuties(string CurDuties);
        void setHoursOfWork(int CurHoursOfWork);
        void setSalary(double CurSalary);

        string getPosName();
        string getDuties();
        int getHoursOfWork();
        double getSalary();
    };
```

POSITION.CPP

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Position.h"
    Position::Position() {

    }

    Position::~Position() {

    }

    void Position::addPosition(Position *CurPosition, vector<Position*> &AllPositions) {
        AllPositions.push_back(CurPosition);
    }

    void Position::setPosName(stri

ng CurPosName) {
        this->positionName = CurPosName;
    }

    void Position::setDuties(string CurDuties) {
        this->duties = CurDuties;
    }

    void Position::setHoursOfWork(int CurHoursOfWork) {
        this->hoursOfWork = CurHoursOfWork;
    }

    void Position::setSalary(double CurSalary) {
        this->salary = CurSalary;
    }

    string Position::getPosName() {
        return positionName;
    }

    string Position::getDuties() {
        return duties;
    }

    int Position::getHoursOfWork() {
        return hoursOfWork;
    }

    double Position::getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Position.h"

void addPosition(vector<Position*> &AllPositions) { 
    Position CurPosition;
    string PosName;
    string duties;
    int hoursOfWork;
    double salary;
    cout << "Введите название должности " << endl;
    cin >> PosName;
    CurPosition.setPosName(PosName);
    cout << "Введите обязанности должности " << endl;
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    getline(cin, duties);
    CurPosition.setDuties(duties);
    cout << " Введите количество рабочих часов в неделю " << endl;
    cin >> hoursOfWork;
    CurPosition.setHoursOfWork(hoursOfWork);
    cout << " Введите зарплату данной должности " << endl;
    cin >> salary;
    CurPosition.setSalary(salary);
    CurPosition.addPosition( &CurPosition, AllPositions);
}

void ShowAllPos(vector <Position*> &AllPos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < AllPos.size(); i++) {
        cout << AllPos[i]->getPosName() << endl;
        cout << AllPos[i]->getDuties() << endl;
        cout << AllPos[i]->getHoursOfWork() << endl;
        cout << AllPos[i]->getSalary() << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    vector <Position*> AllPos;
    addPosition(AllPos);
    addPosition(AllPos);
    cout <<" size vector "<< AllPos.size() << endl;

    ShowAllPos(AllPos);

    return 0;
}
```

нашел, что ошибка появляется тогда, когда в функции `void ShowAllPos(vector <Position*> &AllPos)` ,выводятся строки, числа выводятся, но не те, которые я ввел с консоли. Может кто-нибудь помочь исправить ?

Comment: Конечно же приводить сообщение об ошибке ненужно?

Comment: А текст ошибки можно увидеть?

Comment: @smallup Правильно, выведите его, окаянного, на чистую воду!

Comment: И запустите программу в отладчике, он хотя бы покажет на какой именно строке ошибка.

Comment: @Flowneee Можно по специальному тарифу! Вам лично будет предоставлена скидка в 10%. В ночное время скидка увеличивается до 20%.

Comment: ![ошибка](https://pp.vk.me/c629326/v629326910/25f0c/u_i2NLYHxiQ.jpg) . Если в выводе убрать поля string, то программа работает с числами, но выводит числа не те, которые я ввел

Comment: Какая-то неинформативная ошибка. Берите отладчик и выясняйте какая именно строка в main приводит к ее возникновению.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов К ошибке приводит вывод, строка ShowAllPos(AllPos); , это я уже выяснил, но я не знаю, как исправить это

Comment: Идите в отладчике внутрь, пока не найдете ту строку вашего кода, которая приводит к ошибке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции `addPosition` объект `CurPosition` создается на стеке и после выхода из функции разрушается. Поэтому так делать нельзя:

```
CurPosition.addPosition( &CurPosition, AllPositions);
```

`CurPosition` нужно создавать в куче с помощью new (а лучше использовать `std::shared_ptr`)